# Html form throws 403 error after repeated use

Tags: linux, apache

I've been dealing with a strange, and new, issue on my dedicated server.(there was an Apache update)  I've contacted host support multiple times, but they seem unable to point me in the right direction.  I've created a very simple test script to replicate the problem:

http://irook.com/test.php

If this form is clicked multiple times, about 5-6 times in 3-4 seconds, it triggers a 403 page:

403 Permission Denied You do not have permission for this request /test.php

I've reviewed ModSecurity but do not see any rules that may apply.  I've checked .httaccess and httpd.conf settings but nothing is jumping out at me.

I am guessing that this is a security feature to help block DOS traffic, which is good, but it is affecting normal operations from time to time.  I'd like to review the settings to tweak.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, there is an Apache module called mod_evasive that controls this.